# ¿que debo hacer despues para realizar este programa en java poo?

Tags: java, poo, atributos

Estoy atascado y nose como debo continuar, mi proyecto es el siguiente:

Desarrollar una clase articulo que contenga los siguiente:

- Las propiedades: id, descripcion, y existencia.
- Un constructor que inicialice el objeto articulo al crearlo.
- Metodos para dar entrada a artículos (por compra, devoucion, ajustes etc).
- metodo para dar salida a articulos (por venta, por devolucion al
  proveedor, ajustes etc).
- metodo publicos que accedan a las propiedades    tanto para obtener
  la propiedad o para actualizarla (get y set)

---

Llevo esto:

```java
public class Articulo {
    private int id;
    private String descripcion;
    private int cantidad;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Articulo articulo = new Articulo();
    }
}
```

Comment: He encontrado esta web que te puede ayudar a entender lo que tienes que hacer https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/Java/Objetos-y-Clases

Comment: ya intentaste hacer tu modelo de clases uml?

Comment: Lo que tienes no compila. Empieza primero por eso.

Comment: Lecturas recomendadas del tutorial de Oracle [¿Qué es un objeto?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) y más importante para tu caso [Lección: Clases y objetos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: Tienes que leer mas sobre POO, teniendo la teoria, el ejercicio se hace casi solo. Es clave entender que es un constructor. los metodos GET y SET. Además, entender que es instanciar un objeto, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu problema solo pide que crees la clase Articulo con un simple constructor y metodos getters y setters , respecto al principio de encapsulamiento. Dejo aqui la clase articulo, y los otros dos metodos que pides pues la verdad no tengo claro que mismo se solicita por lo que lo dejo a tu criterio. Recomendacion no uses el metodo main dentro de una clase al cual vas instanciar un objeto, crea otra clase principal en la cual agregues el metodo main, y ahi si ya podras realizar diferentes instancias de diferentes objetos.

Clase Articulo.

```
package tester;

public class Articulo {
    private int id;
    private String descripcion;
    private int cantidad;

    // Este es el constructor que instancia un obejto tipo Articulo.
    public Articulo(int id, String descripcion, int cantidad) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    // Metodos getters y setters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    // Y AQUI AGREGAR LOS OTROS METODOS QUE SOLICITAS.

}
```

Clase principal con un ejemplo de instancia.

```
package tester;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Articulo articulo1 = new Articulo(1, "Azucar de alta calidad", 5);
        Articulo articulo2 = new Articulo(1, "Arroz", 5);
        
        //incluso si tuvieras ejemplo un clase tienda con un atributo que sea su nombre pues tambien podrias instanciar
        //y dar un mejor manejo desde aqui.
        // Tienda obTienda = new Tienda(nombreDeLaTienda);
    }

}
```